# Connecting to Postgres RDS from outside using DataGrip

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, rds

I have setup Postgres RDS instance on AWS. Made it publicly accessible and security group allows all traffic inside and outside.

However I still can't connect from outside network (using DataGrip).

> Connection to jdbc:postgresql://name.abcd.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
>   :5432/mydb failed. Host name.abcd.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com  is
>   unknown. [08001] The connection attempt failed.

I copied the endpoint from AWS console and I'm using the username and password I entered when creating the instance.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How long ago did this happen? THe DNS can take a while to propagate.  What happens when you try "host name.abcd.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com" from your PC (or nslookup/dig)?

Comment: "Host name is unknown" is likely the problem. Do an nslookup to start. If that works check your connect string format.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in DataGrip itself. It put a space between port and host

```
 ...amazonaws.com :5432...
```

To get it working you have to:

- make instance publicly accessible when creating
- setup inbound traffic properly for instance's security group

When this is done, just try this command `psql -h endpoint -U username -d databasename` in you command line so you know you can connect. If it succeeds, you should be able to connect via DataGrip and any other client too.